# textbox implicit conversion from decimal to string

Tags: vb.net

I have this error

> implicit conversion from decimal to string during compilation

```
Public Sub InvoicxeHT()
    Dim Total1 As Decimal = "0,00"
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Total1 += row.Cells(4).Value

    Next
    TotalHT.Text = Total1
End Sub
```

can i know whats the problem

Comment: The main problem is that you haven't set `Option Strict` to `ON`. -- This: `"0,00"` is not a Decimal, it's a String. You should write `Dim total1 As Decimal = .0D`. If the Cells contain actually Decimal value, you need to cast to Decimal their `Value`. If - unfortunately - it's a String Type instead, you need to convert. Or better redesign.

Comment: @Jimi: Better `Dim total1 As Decimal = 0.00D` if he wants to keep the two decimal places

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's just the initial value. You can sum values with any decimal places. You maybe mean *formatting* the final value as Currency (`"C"`, `"C2"`)? Or a string that represents a value with 2 decimal places (e.g., `"N2"`)?

Comment: @Jimi: of course you can always format the final value if you convert it to string(`total1.ToString("N2")`). But i just wanted to note that OP already used two decimal places in the string and that `decimal` retains them internally, so if you use `total1.ToString()` you will get two decimal places. With your code there would be only one. It will retain those initial decimal places even after the calculation in the for-loop.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry, I don't understand what you're saying here. If you declare `dim total1 As Decimal = .0D` and add `total1 += 8.30987D`, when is the single decimal place retained? `total1.ToSting()` will be `8.30987`. Anyway, a string needs to be formatted for presentation, you define how.

Comment: @Jimi: No, of course it will no truncate part of decimals just because the initial value had only two decimal places. But if for example row.Cells(4).Value contains only integers the final value will still have two decimal places. So if there is a single number `10` in the `DataGrifView` the final result in `TotalHT.Text` will be `10.00` not `10`. If you initialize the decimal with `Dim total1 As Decimal = 0D` the final result would be `10`. But you're right, you should [ensure the correct format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub InvoicxeHT()
    Dim Total1 As Decimal = "0,00"
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Total1 += CDec(row.Cells(4).Value) ' Or CInt()

    Next
    TotalHT.Text = Total1
End Sub
```